# Looping REPT Function with Relative Cell Referencing in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that produces in-cell graphing as seen over at [http://www.juiceanalytics.com/writing/more-on-excel-in-cell-graphing](http://www.juiceanalytics.com/writing/more-on-excel-in-cell-graphing/). I'm still fairly new to VBA and have little experience of using Worksheet Functions; this is what I've attempted so far.

If someone could help me resolve this it'd be great, because I've trawled Google and can't find anything!

```
Sub GraphsInCell()
Dim inCellBar As String, barData As Long

barData = ActiveSheet.Range("E4:E" & FinalRow).Value
'repeats "|" string based on Column E values in order to 
'produce a small in-cell bar
inCellBar = Application.WorksheetFunction.Rept("|", barData)

For Each i In ActiveSheet.Range("F4:F" & FinalRow)
    With ActiveSheet.Range("F4:F" & FinalRow)
        .Value = inCellBar
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

This is a small snippet from a larger body of code, but everything else works fine. The offending code is all above.

I basically need to have the REPT function use the values in a relative cell as 'number_times' (eg =REPT("|", number_times)). Anyone know how to do this or what's wrong with my code snippet?

Thanks in advance guys.

---

As background info, I've got a small table with the headings, 'Sender', 'Emails', 'Letters', 'Faxes', 'Total' and 'Graph'. 'Total' is SUM of preceeding three columns and I want graph to contain the REPT function. Really simple set-up.

---

Final code sample from Lunatik's answer and Dick Kusleika's comment is below:

```
Sub GraphsInCell()
Dim c As Range
Dim TheRange As Range

Set TheRange = Range("E4:E20")

For Each c In TheRange.Cells
    If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
        c.Offset(0, 1) = String(c.Value, "|")
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of the context of your code as it won't work without additional variables being set, but I think this does what you are trying to achieve and should point in the right direction for updating your code.

```
Sub GraphsInCell()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim TheRange As Range

    Set TheRange = Range("E4:E20")

    For Each c In TheRange.Cells
        If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
            c.Offset(0, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Rept("|", c.Value)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Obviously you'll need to use your own method for defining the range being used.

Also, although the code handles text or empty cells it will error on negative values.  How this is might be best handled would probably depend on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the response Lunatik, the sample you've provided an Runtime Error 424 - Object Required. I've not covered debugging yet, so I'm not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Strange, there is nothing unusual in that code and nothing that I'm aware of that would throw an object error.  Does the same error happen if you paste the code into an empty module in a fresh workbook?  There are no dependencies so it should work in a brand-new workbook.

On what line does it error? Or does it error when it is compiling the p-code, i.e. not on a line.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, my work PC just died a death. I managed to test the snippet in a seperate module and it worked fine. I didn't get a chance to test the error type because the machine died but it didn't highlight a line. I'll have to write it again, because it hasn't saved, but in the meantime, do you know what it might have been?

Comment: If you don't have an ActiveSheet (like if you put the code in an add-in), then the unqualified Range reference would fail, but I don't think it would be that message.  Also, consider using the String() function.  The Worksheet function call seems unnecessary.

Comment: String works perfectly Dick. So I guess Lunatik's answer along with your comment solves the problem. Thanks guys.